# What transistors are used in DC-AC part of HVDC?

Tags: transistors, igbt, hvdc

I know that thyristors are used for rectification, [that results in choppy DC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HVDC_converter). But what about other side of line? How do they convert such high voltage back to AC? Highest voltage IGBT I found is 6.5kV.

Do they connect them in series to achieve higher voltage for inverters (is it even possible)?

Would inductive loads cause harmonics, like in automotive 12VDC/230VAC inverters connected to motors (blender, power drill)?

Comment: Thyristors can be used at both ends.

Answer (score 1):

Many years ago, straight series connection of IGBTs to form a two or three level inverter.

These days, it's all MMC (modular multilevel converter), still using IGBTs. Schematic borrowed from https://www.plexim.com/support/application-examples/938

[image]

Inductive loads functions pretty much as in your AC grid overwise, they rob VA rating without active power. HVDC stations tend to have a round P-Q-graph so to support inductive or capacitive current, available peak active power will drop.
Image borrowed from https://www.researchgate.net/publication/329473821_Exponential_Phase-Locked_Loop_Photovoltaic_Model_for_PHIL_Applications
[image]

Comment: (What's DER? Distributed Energy Resources? (Like windmills? what use would over- or under-excitation be unless advantageous for the grid?))

Comment: @greybeard Seems so yes. I haven't seen the term used in this regard before, but the graph was what I was after.

Comment: You can increasingly get modules for MMCs that use SiC MOSFETs, too. As I understand it, they're not quite common in power transmission systems yet, but they probably will be in the near future.